# Elastic Index name having # character

Tags: elasticsearch

While I was referring to [6.4 version docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html), I noticed following about index name limitation:

> Cannot include \, /, *, ?, ", <, >, |,  (space character), ,, #

However, when I tried creating an index with '>' character in it, following error was returned:

Input:
PUT request on : `http://localhost:9200/tw>itter`

Output:

```
    {
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "invalid_index_name_exception",
                "reason": "Invalid index name [tw>itter], must not contain the following characters [ , \", *, \\, <, |, ,, >, /, ?]",
                "index_uuid": "_na_",
                "index": "tw>itter"
            }
        ],
        "type": "invalid_index_name_exception",
        "reason": "Invalid index name [tw>itter], must not contain the following characters [ , \", *, \\, <, |, ,, >, /, ?]",
        "index_uuid": "_na_",
        "index": "tw>itter"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Notice, the error string do not have # character as a limitation.

> Invalid index name [tw>itter], must not contain the following characters [ , \", *, \, <, |, ,, >, /, ?]

So, Could anyone confirm, whether # is allowed ?
P.S : If i tried to create index with #, it creates the index but truncate everything beyond #.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#` character is not allowed in an index name, even if you URL encode it it won't work:

```
PUT test%23hash
```

Result:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "invalid_index_name_exception",
        "reason": "Invalid index name [test#hash], must not contain '#'",
        "index_uuid": "_na_",
        "index": "test#hash"
      }
    ],
    "type": "invalid_index_name_exception",
    "reason": "Invalid index name [test#hash], must not contain '#'",
    "index_uuid": "_na_",
    "index": "test#hash"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

The ultimate source of truth is the code and we can see in [`Strings.java` (L376-377)](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/237650e9c054149fd08213b38a81a3666c1868e5/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/Strings.java#L376-L377) that the forbidden characters are `'\\', '/', '*', '?', '"', '<', '>', '|', ' ', ','`

However, this is not the whole story, the [`MetaDataIndexTemplateService` class](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/09bf4e5f007492b5f765941080518c2de2381b35/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/cluster/metadata/MetaDataIndexTemplateService.java#L260-L293) also has an interesting `validate` method that rejects all the above characters, as well as the `#` character.

Trying to create an index with a non URL-encoded `#` sign, as you saw, works but with anything removed from the `#` sign onwards. This is because the `#` sign is a reserved character in URLs and delimits [query fragments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), so it's definitely valid to specify it in the URL, but it will be stripped out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, the docs are right aboit the # usage but the error message does not has # in the list. But as you pointed out the # check is done in some other class than other characters, its not the right thing to have the # in the list specified in error message for other characters.